# Jquery tabs - how to makes it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using code of http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/us8uc/.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs-container">
<ul class="tabs-menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
        <p>c</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        <p>b</p>

    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        <p>a</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href");
    $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
    $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

});

CSS:
In the link at top, too long to paste it here.

It works perfectly, but I need to make divs with same tabs many time on my site.
With this code, doing anything on 1st tab, making other tabs to colapse.

I was trying do this with other classes/id but it doesnt work, and my js skill is too poor to invent way to fix it.

TIA

Comment: Not really understand what you want but if you want to add more tabs to your page you just have to copy the code and modify the Ids of your tabs and the hrefs of your links to point to the right tab.

Comment: That's is what I want avoid, I need to have like 20 same tabs on my page.

So, lets say we have 2 tabs.
Pressing 1st "link" on 1st tab, maks actions on both Tabs.
I want make it to work only on tab where link was clicked.

Comment: @Krece Are you trying to OPEN a link inside a tab? (it is possible, just trying to understand, is that what you want?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround way without changing too much:

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href=".tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="tab-content tab-1">
            <p>A</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-2">
            <p>B</p>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-3">
            <p>C</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-4">
            <p>D</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href=".tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href=".tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div class="tab-content tab-1">
            <p>E</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-2">
            <p>F</p>

        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-3">
            <p>G</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content tab-4">
            <p>H </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(this).parents().eq(2).find(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(this).parents().eq(2).find(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

And in the CSS, change the `#tab-1` to `.tab-1`.

Basically, in order to make more than 2, copy and paste the `tabs-container` div and everthing inside, then just change the content.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Us8uc/6272/

Comment: In this demo, when you press "tab 1" in second div, maks it collapse :/

Comment: I forgot to change th `#tab-1` to `.tab-1`

Comment: Found this too :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't have multiple id's, i ve used data-id attribute... So, html is slightly changed:

```
<div class="tabs-container">
    <ul class="tabs-menu">
        <li class="current"><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab-4">Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab">
        <div data-id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sit amet purus urna. Proin dictum fringilla enim, sit amet suscipit dolor dictum in. Maecenas porttitor, est et malesuada congue, ligula elit fermentum massa, sit amet porta odio est at velit. Sed nec turpis neque. Fusce at mi felis, sed interdum tortor. Nullam pretium, est at congue mattis, nibh eros pharetra lectus, nec posuere libero dui consectetur arcu. Quisque convallis facilisis fermentum. Nam tincidunt, diam nec dictum mattis, nunc dolor ultrices ipsum, in mattis justo turpis nec ligula. Curabitur a ante mauris. Integer placerat imperdiet diam, facilisis pretium elit mollis pretium. Sed lobortis, eros non egestas suscipit, dui dui euismod enim, ac ultricies arcu risus at tellus. Donec imperdiet congue ligula, quis vulputate mauris ultrices non. Aliquam rhoncus, arcu a bibendum congue, augue risus tincidunt massa, vel vehicula diam dolor eget felis.</p>
        </div>
        <div data-id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
            <p>Donec semper dictum sem, quis pretium sem malesuada non. Proin venenatis orci vel nisl porta sollicitudin. Pellentesque sit amet massa et orci malesuada facilisis vel vel lectus. Etiam tristique volutpat auctor. Morbi nec massa eget sem ultricies fermentum id ut ligula. Praesent aliquet adipiscing dictum. Suspendisse dignissim dui tortor. Integer faucibus interdum justo, mattis commodo elit tempor id. Quisque ut orci orci, sit amet mattis nulla. Suspendisse quam diam, feugiat at ullamcorper eget, sagittis sed eros. Proin tortor tellus, pulvinar at imperdiet in, egestas sed nisl. Aenean tempor neque ut felis dignissim ac congue felis viverra. </p>

        </div>
        <div data-id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
            <p>Duis egestas fermentum ipsum et commodo. Proin bibendum consectetur elit, hendrerit porta mi dictum eu. Vestibulum adipiscing euismod laoreet. Vivamus lobortis tortor a odio consectetur pulvinar. Proin blandit ornare eros dictum fermentum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur laoreet, ante aliquet molestie laoreet, lectus odio fringilla purus, id porttitor erat velit vitae mi. Nullam posuere nunc ut justo sollicitudin interdum. Donec suscipit eros nec leo condimentum fermentum. Nunc quis libero massa. Integer tempus laoreet lectus id interdum. Integer facilisis egestas dui at convallis. Praesent elementum nisl et erat iaculis a blandit ligula mollis. Vestibulum vitae risus dui, nec sagittis arcu. Nullam tortor enim, placerat quis eleifend in, viverra ac lacus. Ut aliquam sapien ut metus hendrerit auctor dapibus justo porta. </p>
        </div>
        <div data-id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
            <p>Proin sollicitudin tincidunt quam, in egestas dui tincidunt non. Maecenas tempus condimentum mi, sed convallis tortor iaculis eu. Cras dui dui, tempor quis tempor vitae, ullamcorper in justo. Integer et lorem diam. Quisque consequat lectus eget urna molestie pharetra. Cras risus lectus, lobortis sit amet imperdiet sit amet, eleifend a erat. Suspendisse vel luctus lectus. Sed ac arcu nisi, sit amet ornare tellus. Pellentesque nec augue a nibh pharetra scelerisque quis sit amet felis. Nullam at enim at lacus pretium iaculis sit amet vel nunc. Praesent sapien felis, tincidunt vitae blandit ut, mattis at diam. Suspendisse ac sapien eget eros venenatis tempor quis id odio. Donec lacus leo, tincidunt eget molestie at, pharetra cursus odio. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, to get closest element, well...use closest() method:

```
$(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
    var tab = $(this).attr("href").replace('#','');

    $(this).closest('.tabs-container').find(".tab-content").css('display','none');


   $(this).closest('.tabs-container').find('[data-id='+tab+']').fadeIn();




});
```

And demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a0zLv7my/5/